# Merge two states North and South Dakota in geom_map

Tags: r, ggplot2

In this example of plotting US States using geom_map

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

us <- map_data("state")

arr <- USArrests %>% 
  add_rownames("region") %>% 
  mutate(region=tolower(region))

gg <- ggplot()
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=us, map=us,
                    aes(x=long, y=lat, map_id=region),
                    fill="#ffffff", color="#ffffff", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + geom_map(data=arr, map=us,
                    aes(fill=Murder, map_id=region),
                    color="#ffffff", size=0.15)
gg <- gg + scale_fill_continuous(low='thistle2', high='darkred', 
                                 guide='colorbar')
gg <- gg + labs(x=NULL, y=NULL)
gg <- gg + coord_map("albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45) 
gg <- gg + theme(panel.border = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(panel.background = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.ticks = element_blank())
gg <- gg + theme(axis.text = element_blank())
gg
```

How do I merge two states together , for example, North and South Dakota, how do I get rid of the boundary between these two states and show them as "Megakotas" .

Comment: Is using `geom_map` required or do you just want to have the map?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need to use `geom_map` and are willing to dive into some of the spatial packages in R such as `sf`, you can achieve this as follows. Here's my example using the GADM Database of Global Administrative Regions to pull the state boundaries.

1. Use `raster::getData` as a convenient shortcut to get the boundary files. `level` refers to the administrative level, where `0` is the country and `1` is the first level below that. Note that this will save a file into your working directory. I convert to the Albers projection as your example does using `st_transform`.
2. Join the polygons onto the `USArrests` dataset and use the convenient `dplyr` tools to combine the Dakotas. Note that I sum the values for the two states although I'm not clear that's the right thing to do (isn't this value a mean so maybe we should take the mean?) This automatically unions the two states' boundaries.
3. Before plotting, I use `st_simplify` to reduce the number of vertices to make plotting faster. Then we can simply use `geom_sf` and get the desired plot.

```r
library(raster)
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)
# library(sp)
# library(rgeos)

states <- getData("GADM", country = "USA", level = 1) %>%
  st_as_sf() %>%
  st_transform(crs = 3310)

megakotas <- states %>% 
  left_join(
    y = rownames_to_column(USArrests, var = "State"),
    by = c("NAME_1" = "State")
  ) %>%
  filter(!NAME_1 %in% c("District of Columbia", "Alaska", "Hawaii")) %>%
  mutate(State = fct_collapse(NAME_1, Megakotas = c("North Dakota", "South Dakota"))) %>%
  group_by(State) %>%
  summarise(Murder = sum(Murder)) %>%
  st_simplify(dTolerance = 1000)

ggplot(megakotas) +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = Murder)) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c() +
  theme_minimal()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-03-07 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: Good answer, but how is this "a lot" simpler? You have about the same lines of code as my answer does minus the themes.

Comment: Not needing to manage separate objects feels conceptually simpler, but that's a matter of opinion I suppose. I'll un-editorialize it.

Comment: Gotcha. I'm just curious to see why you think it's simpler

Answer (score 1):

Turns out to be more work then I have expected, but here is my solution. The basic idea is to use the `maps::map` function along with `boundary = TRUE` and `interior = FALSE`  to get the coordinates of `"north dekota"` and `"south dekota"` *without* the interior boundary and plot that separately from other states.

### Step 1: Grab "megakotas" coordinates...

```
# To install gissr
# library(devtools)
# Install dependency
# install_github("skgrange/threadr")
# Install gissr
# install_github("skgrange/gissr")

library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(gissr)

us_coord <- map_data("state") 
megakotas_coord <- map("state", regions = c("north dakota", "south dakota"), 
                       boundary = TRUE, interior = FALSE, plot = FALSE)[c("x", "y")] %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  sort_points(y = "y", x = "x") %>%
  mutate(region = "megakotas")
```

**Output:**

```
> head(megakotas_coord)
          x        y    region
1 -104.0491 45.21210 megakotas
2 -104.0434 45.87673 megakotas
3 -104.0491 45.93976 megakotas
4 -104.0491 45.93976 megakotas
5 -104.0434 46.27207 megakotas
6 -104.0434 46.53563 megakotas
```

Here, we use `gissr::sort_points` to sort the coordinates from `map` in clockwise order, then replaced `region` with `"megakotas"` instead of `"north dakota"` and `"south dakota"`.

### Step 2: Replace "north dakota" and "south dakota" with "megakotas" in `arr` and sum their values...

```
arr <- USArrests %>% 
  add_rownames("region") %>%
  mutate(region = replace(tolower(region), tolower(region) %in% c("north dakota", "south dakota"), 
                          "megakotas")) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate_all(sum)
```

**Output:**

```
> arr %>% filter(region == "megakotas")
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   region [1]
  region    Murder Assault UrbanPop  Rape
  <chr>      <dbl>   <int>    <int> <dbl>
1 megakotas    4.6     131       89  20.1
2 megakotas    4.6     131       89  20.1
```

### Step 3: Plot `us_coord` and `megakotas_coord` separately, and use the `data` argument in `geom_map` to control what gets printed...

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mapping = aes(map_id=region)) +
  geom_map(data = filter(arr, region != "megakotas"), 
           map = us_coord, aes(fill = Murder),
           size = 0.15, color="#ffffff") +
  expand_limits(x = us_coord$long, y = us_coord$lat)
```

[image]

```
ggplot(mapping = aes(map_id=region)) +
  geom_map(data = filter(arr, region == "megakotas"),
           map = megakotas_coord, aes(fill = Murder), 
           size = 0.15, color = "#ffffff") + 
  expand_limits(x = us_coord$long, y = us_coord$lat)
```

[image]

### Final Step: Combine everything...

```
# To install gissr
# library(devtools)
# Install dependency
# install_github("skgrange/threadr")
# Install gissr
# install_github("skgrange/gissr")

library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(maps)
library(gissr)

us_coord <- map_data("state") 
megakotas_coord <- map("state", regions = c("north dakota", "south dakota"), 
                       boundary = TRUE, interior = FALSE, plot = FALSE)[c("x", "y")] %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  sort_points(y = "y", x = "x") %>%
  mutate(region = "megakotas")

arr <- USArrests %>% 
  add_rownames("region") %>%
  mutate(region = replace(tolower(region), tolower(region) %in% c("north dakota", "south dakota"), 
                          "megakotas")) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate_all(sum) 

ggplot(mapping = aes(map_id=region, fill = Murder)) +
  geom_map(data = filter(arr, region != "megakotas"),
           map = us_coord, size = 0.15, color = "#ffffff") +
  geom_map(data = filter(arr, region == "megakotas"),
           map = megakotas_coord, size = 0.15, color = "#ffffff") + 
  expand_limits(x = us_coord$long, y = us_coord$lat) +
  scale_fill_continuous(low = 'thistle2', high = 'darkred', guide = 'colorbar') +
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL) +
  coord_map("albers", lat0 = 39, lat1 = 45)  +
  theme(panel.border = element_blank(),
      panel.background = element_blank(),
      axis.ticks = element_blank(),
      axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

**Note:** This solution would be much simpler if `map_data` respects `boundary = TRUE` and `interior = FALSE`, which it should according to the documentation of `map_data` (`?map_data` clearly says one can pass other arguments to `maps::map()`). Somehow `map_data("state", region = c("north dakota", "south dakota"), boundary = TRUE, interior = FALSE)` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: This solution doesn't work once you add more states than just the two Dakotas.