# Merging U.S. states from map_data

Tags: r, ggplot2, merge, maps, gis

I would like to plot a world map where the U.S. is divided into two regions:
`blue_states <- tolower(c("California", "Illinois", "New York", "New Jersey", "Washington", "Massachusetts", "Oregon", "Connecticut", "Delaware", "Rhode Island", "District of Columbia", "Vermont"))`
and `non_blue_states`.

Crucially, I don't want to display U.S. states' boundaries (except the boundaries between the two regions).

I have a dataframe with two columns: `country` and `value`, with values between -1 and +1. The map should be colored according to `value`. The variable `country` spans all countries except the U.S., which is covered by `country` = `Blue USA` and `Non-Blue USA`.

I have found several related questions, but I am not able to make them work. For example, [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72708323/how-merge-specific-states-together-by-group-with-one-label-in-ggplot2-in-r) uses the package `USAboundaries`, which has been removed from CRAN, and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54893344/merge-two-states-north-and-south-dakota-in-geom-map) plots only the U.S., not the whole world.

Ideally, I would like to use the map `ggplot2::map_data(map = "state")` for the U.S. states and merge it with `ggplot2::map_data(map = "world")` for the other countries. But I am obviously open to other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `rnaturalearth` and `tidyverse`:

```r
library(rnaturalearth)
library(tidyverse)

blue_states <- c("California", "Illinois", "New York", "New Jersey", 
                 "Washington", "Massachusetts", "Oregon", "Connecticut", 
                 "Delaware", "Rhode Island", "District of Columbia", 
                 "Vermont")

ne_states(country = 'United States of America', returnclass = 'sf') %>%
  mutate(is_blue = name %in% blue_states) %>%
  group_by(is_blue) %>%
  summarize(geometry = st_union(geometry)) %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(aes(fill = is_blue), color = NA) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c('red3', 'blue2')) +
  coord_sf(xlim = c(-180, -60)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.position = 'none')
```

[image]

Or, if you just want the continental USA, you could change the `coord_sf` to `coord_sf(xlim = c(-125, -60), ylim = c(20, 50))` to get:

[image]

Comment: I fail installing `rnaturalearthhires`. I have R 4.3.1.

Comment: What code did you try to install it @bixiou?

Comment: Different things: `install.packages("rnaturalearthhires")`, `remotes::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")`, `devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")`, `install.packages("rnaturalearthhires", repos = "https://ropensci.r-universe.dev", type = "source")`. Every time I enter an infinite loop.

Comment: It worked well on another computer! 
Before I can validate the answer, @allan-cameron would you mind explainind how you then merge this map with a world map, where the U.S. is split into two countries (blue and non-blue)?

Comment: I managed to install it on the first computer as well, with `devtools::install_github("ropensci/rnaturalearthhires")` using the terminal instead of RStudio.

Comment: I didn't manage to merge this U.S. map with a world map. @allan-cameron, how would you do?